# Creating site contact detail in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, customization

I'm dabbling into Wordpress without really knowing where I'm going.

I'm not sure if it's the right way, but I need to create a contact detail list for a web site (email, phone number etc...) displayed in the site header.

I'm not sure where to store this kind of global info in Wordpress so I have created a custom post type (contact) to allow the site owner to edit the details.

But now I can't seem to be able to pull the info on any other page than the contact page (which I will also have to remove from navigation and view.)

Does anybody have any tips on how to do that?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your looking to make the contact info editable ( for only the owner of the site ) you will want to look in to a theme options panel. Look up wp-ask.me on youtube or http://wp-ask.me and he has a theme options panel you can add to any theme and has video tutorials on how to do so. good luck

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has its pros and cons...and you're better set to find out about them by checking out all the support documentation that WP has to offer, including asking at their forums. To do what you're describing, look in your site's theme folder and find the header file http://wordpress.org/support/topic/finding-the-header-file Then edit that to include the text or image you want to display on every page on the site.

Comment: I have that, it's not the problem. I'm trying to fill the value for the email, phone number, etc in the header, from the contact custom post type that I have created. bu they show only when the url is localhost/contact/

Comment: I don't know that you can pull info from a WP post into the header file. (That's one of the reasons I didn't use WP - it didn't work the way I wanted to work, so I chose another CMS.) You have to edit the header file itself if you want to display the contact info in the site header.